# CheckedNodes siempre está vacia

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo una aplicación en asp.net & c# y uso un componente `TreeView` insertado sobre un `updatepanel`.

He metido las rutinas en js para que checkee correctamente y en orden jerárquico nodos padres e hijos y lo hace bien.

El problema es cuando quiero obtener los nodos chequeados desde la parte de código en C#. Es como si no se "enterara" de que se han marcado checks. Pienso que es un problema de Posteo pero no sé dónde indicarlo. Ya he indicado en el `Page_Load`

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    TreeView.Attributes.Add("onclick", "OnTreeClick(event)");
}
```

pero sigue sin hacer nada. Qué me estoy dejando para que realmente se rellene la `checkednodes` collection?.
Gracias.

Comment: El UpdatePanel a pesar que no actualiza toda la pagina sigue por debajo realizando un post al servidor, ahora bien en que evento cargas los nodos del treeview ?

Comment: En: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){}. El treeview se carga desde un directoryInfo. estoy trabajando con estructuras de directorios.

Answer (score 0):

Si cargas los nodos del treeview en el `Page_Load` tienes que poner ese codigo dentro del bloque que valida el postback

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    //aqui cargas los datos del treeview

    TreeView.Attributes.Add("onclick", "OnTreeClick(event)");
}
```

ya que al ejecutarse el evento volveran a cargarse perdiendo la seleccion

Comment: He probado ya a meter dentro la rutina de carga del treeview. Pero sigue igual..

Comment: De todas formas estoy viendo que quizás debiera haber usado OnChangeChecked() en vez de ontreeclick() aunque supongo que el nombre da igual. OnTreeClick creo que es para sólo seleccionar como tu dices.

Comment: Por cierto.. gracias!!.

Comment: Buenas de nuevo!!. He colocado la carga antes de la linea del evento OnTreeClick como me decias y ahora funciona correctamente ;).  

if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                CargaTV(TVPadre, RutaEstructuras);
                TVPadre.ExpandAll();
                TVPadre.Attributes.Add("onclick", "OnTreeClick(event)");
                
            }
Te debo una!!.